# Why is RVM trying to install Rubygems instead of Ruby with the 'rvm install' command?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.0 on my Debian server and decided to do this via RVM. I downloaded it using:

```
~$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

But when I try to install Ruby, it looks like RVM is trying to install Rubygems instead.

```
~$ rvm install 2.0.0
=> 'ruby' was not found, cannot install rubygems unless ruby is present (Do you have an RVM ruby installed & selected?)
```

I've checked the RVM documentation and `rvm install <ruby version>` is definitely the command for installing Ruby, not Rubygems. So why is the issue above occuring? Thank you!

EDIT:

Output of 'rvm info':

    `[name]@debian-server:~/.rvm/rubies$ rvm info`

```
system:
uname:       "Linux debian-server 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
system:      "debian/7/x86_64"
bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
zsh:         " => not installed"

rvm:
version:      "rvm 1.24.5 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
updated:      "33 minutes 56 seconds ago"
path:         "/home/[name]/.rvm"

homes:
gem:          "not set"
ruby:         "not set"

binaries:
ruby:         ""
irb:          ""
gem:          ""
rake:         "/home/[name]/.rvm/bin/rake"

environment:
PATH:              "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/[name]/.rvm/bin"
GEM_HOME:     ""
GEM_PATH:     ""
MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
IRBRC:        ""
RUBYOPT:      ""
gemset:       ""
```

Output of 'rvm requirements':

```
~$ rvm requirements
Checking requirements for debian. Requirements installation successful.
```

Comment: is 'rvm requirements' passed?

Comment: In addition to @BuDen's suggestion, run `rvm info`

Comment: `rvm` tries to install `rubygems` as part of its installation procedure. Maybe it's having trouble finding the `ruby` it installed?

Comment: @BuDen, yes - it returns 'Requirements installation successful' when I run that command. Trying to install ruby again results in the same error.

Comment: @tadman I would think that if it didn't return with that error right away. I'm not seeing any output showing that it's compiling and installing Ruby at all.

Comment: you might need to paste the whole logs of what rvm is doing if you really want help

Comment: @bjhaid You're right. I added the terminal output to my post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand how you arrived at this situation, but if you want ruby 2.0 installed via RVM, then I would suggest the following:

```
rvm implode
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Then make sure you source  ~/.bash_profile (as mentioned in the installation output) to load RVM in each new shell.

Comment: I don't understand it either! I removed RVM with `rvm implode`, re-logged in, and installed the RVM script using that command. Same error. Thank you anyway!

Comment: What is the output of `rvm list` ?

Comment: `rvm rubies`
    `# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.`

Comment: did you source ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile as the case might be